Retrieve elements from list based on start/end date in PnP search
I have a list with alerts I only want to be shown in PnP search whenever the elements date is within the range of StartDate and Enddate (columns startdate and enddate).
Right now I only got
{searchTerms}
path:https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/Lists/Alerts AND LastModifiedTime=today
in my query template to find my list but "LastModifiedTime" needs to be changed to between start and end date.

Can you provide your sample input and expected output?

You could refer to following url to filter by date
https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items?$filter=Date ge datetime%272017-19-05%27

